# Is there a way to append child rows to datatables using Vue JavaScript and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, datatables

I went through the documentation Vue Datatables [Vue Datatable Component](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue). I managed to implement the the datatable using typescript and vue js. Below is the Datatable component:

```
<template>

<DataTable 
:data="data"
 class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</DataTable>
```

```
<style scoped>
@import 'datatables.net-dt';
</style>

    <script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent} from "vue";
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3';
import DataTablesLib from 'datatables.net';
DataTable.use(DataTablesLib);

const data = [
  ['Pistone', 'Sanjama', 'pistone@ghii.org'],
  ['Timothy', 'Banda','timothy@ghii.org'],
  ['Blessings', 'Chidambe', 'blessings@ghii.org']
];

export default defineComponent({
name: "DataRequestDatatable",
components: {
    DataTable,
},
data(){
    return { data }
}
});
</script>
```

I have successfully display the table and add columns etc and they do not have a documentation of doing this. Does anyone have an Idea of how I can implement the child rows into this table using Vue and Typescript?

The image below shows the child rows in action:
[image]

Comment: The docs here https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue#Reactive-data shows how to add rows to the datatable